# cURL couldn't connect to host, but it connects to my domain address

Tags: php, linux, curl, wget, firewall

I am new to Linux. I had the php project in the Linux server. I am using the [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se) command in my php page to access Google, but it says it couldn't access the host.

From the command line, I can ping the Google site, while cURL and [Wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) commands fail.

I had checked the firewall: `selinux=disabled` and `selinuxtype=targeted`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this command from a terminal

```
telnet www.google.com 80
```

Do you get any output? Like `Connected to www.google.com`? If not, then the outgoing access to google.com on port 80 is blocked.

Ping uses the [ICMP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol). cURL (and [telnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet)) uses [TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) on port 80 or 443.